# print Active reports using default printer on c#

Tags: printing, activereports

I'm trying to print an active reports document but it needs to print directly, without showing the printer window, but printing directly on the default printer.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Document object's print method has an overload which allows passing in true/false for "show print dialog" and "show progress dialog". From [the documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports.Document~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.Document~Print%28Boolean,Boolean,Boolean%29.html) the signature is below:

```
public bool Print( 
   bool showPrintDialog,
   bool showPrintProgressDialog,
   bool usePrintingThread
)
```

You might call it on a report that as follows:

```
 var myReport = new SalesActiveReport();
 myReport.Run();
 myReport.Document.Print(false, false, false);
```